# Remove dynamically added div on timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like a `div` to appear for a short duration of time and then go away.

So, I dynamically create the `div` on the click of a button, and then after some work is done, I'd like it to be removed from the DOM.

So, I set up a timer like so:

```
var contentJoinTab = $("#...");
var divIdSubscribePleaseWait = "div-subscribe-pleasewait";


btnSubscribe.on("click", function (event) {

    displaySubscriptionWait();

    postMailingListSubscription();

});

function displaySubscriptionWait() {
    var s = `<div id = ${divIdSubscribePleaseWait} class = "${classMailingListPleaseWait}">Please wait...</div>`;

    contentJoinTab.append(s);
};

function postMailingListSubscription() {

    // fake for now
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        removeSubscriptionWait();
    }, 4000);

};

function removeSubscriptionWait() {
    contentJoinTab.parent(`${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}`).remove();

   // I've even tried the following to no avail
   // $(`${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}`).remove();
   // contentJoinTab.find(`${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}`).remove();
};
```

However, even though there is no error in the call to the `remove()` method, the `div` I am trying to remove remains in the DOM and is visible.

I do understand event propagation but my understanding is that that's not relevant here. That would have been relevant if I wanted to attach an event to the `click` (or any other event) of the dynamically created `div` or any of its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be missing `#` when calling `removeSubscriptionWait` And also need `""` for `id = ${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}`.
Please see changes below in case it isn't clear:

```js
function displaySubscriptionWait() {
    var s = `<div id = "${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}" class = "${classMailingListPleaseWait}">Please wait...</div>`;

    contentJoinTab.append(s);
};

function postMailingListSubscription() {

    // fake for now
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        removeSubscriptionWait();
    }, 4000);

};

function removeSubscriptionWait() {
    contentJoinTab.parent(`#${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}`).remove();

   // I've even tried the following to no avail
   $(`#${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}`).remove();
};
```

Comment: damn it! That was the thing. The missing pound/hash sign was the thing. Silly me! Thank you. :-)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Out of curiosity were  ```""``` needed for the element or  just the ```#``` was missing?

Comment: No, just adding the missing `#` worked. I still haven't noticed what you're referring to as `""`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting outerHTML of that div to null

```js
function addDiv() {
  let s = "<div id='tempDiv'>Temporary Div</div>"
  let root = document.getElementById("root")
  root.innerHTML += s;
}

function removeDiv() {
  let theDiv = document.getElementById("tempDiv");
  theDiv.outerHTML=""
}


addDiv()

setTimeout(removeDiv,2000)
```

```html
<div id=root>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I do understand the workaround and have a few more in mind. I am trying to understand why the `remove` method does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

You have appended that div as a child of `contentJoinTab` but when you go to remove it you are looking for it as being parent of `contentJoinTab`

You also need to add the ID prefix in selector

try changing

```
contentJoinTab.parent(`${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}`).remove();
```

To

```
contentJoinTab.find(`#${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}`).remove();
```

Comment: Thank you, I recall having tried that (`find`), too, and I tried it again after reading your answer but to no avail.

Comment: Really need a runnable [mcve] to see why. Create  a demo that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0):

update **removeSubscriptionWait** function :

```
function removeSubscriptionWait() {

    contentJoinTab.find('#'+`${divIdSubscribePleaseWait}`).remove();
};
```